# use a metric in HPA which was pushed to prometheus pushgateway

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, hpa, prometheus-pushgateway

I'm pushing a metric via python client to push gateway in prometheus.
Im able to query the metric - "QYZ_normal" in the prometheus UI and get result.

Im trying to understand how to utilize that metric for HPA (i have setup prometheus-adapter)

The following command returns alot of metrics but not the one i have pushed to prometheus

```
kubectl get --raw /apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/ | grep QYZ_normal
```

Do i look in the wrong API?  how can i utilize my metric in HPA?

Comment: Did you configure the adapter for the new metric?

Comment: @coderanger i added it to adapter config map  thanks for noticing ,  but the question now if it should be query able via the custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/ ?